# place png overlay image on mouseover on textlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, png, overlay

I have a normale jpg-photo and 2 textlink. When the user mouseover textlink 1  I would like to show a transparent png-photo on top of the jpg-photo, and when the user mouseover textlink 2, I would like to show another png-photo on top of the jpg. On mouseout the png should disappear again.

Possible? And can it be done with CSS alone or do I need javascript to?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Depending on your HTML structure you may need Javascript or you may not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with JQuery, JS or CSS, depending on your requirements. 
Good script to use is here:

http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use hover CSS selector to solve such kind of problems depending upon html layout of your page

```
#11:hover img {
display:inline:
Add other blocks 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request can be done easily using the power of jQuery :)
I made something using jQuery and you can find it here 

http://jsfiddle.net/xrmqq/

It is close to what you want to do.